# RibbonControlsLibrary - different behaviors tab navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

Ribbon control has different behaviors for tab order.

```
<r:Ribbon>
    <r:RibbonTab Header="Header 1">
        <r:RibbonGroup Header="Group 1">
            <r:RibbonButton Label="Button1" LargeImageSource="button.png" />
        </r:RibbonGroup>
    </r:RibbonTab>
    <r:RibbonTab Header="Header 2">
        <r:RibbonGroup Header="Group 2">
            <r:RibbonButton Label="Button2" LargeImageSource="button.png" />
        </r:RibbonGroup>
    </r:RibbonTab>
</r:Ribbon>
```

If user clicks on the second tab and clicks "Tab" button, Ribbon changes selected tab to the first. But if user selects the second tab by clicking on "Tab" button and then clicks "Tab" button, Ribbon doesn't change selected tab. How can I fix it?

Comment: You sure it's not just cycling to the next TabStop?

Comment: When you navigate to tab by TabKey all works fine and as expect. But when you clicks on another tab and press few times on TabKey, it returns to previous tab.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is to catch the "Tab" Key Event and manually navigate in the Ribbon.

**Xaml:**

```
<r:Ribbon PreviewKeyDown="Ribbon_PreviewKeyDown" x:Name="ribbon">
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void Ribbon_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
  {

    if (ribbon.SelectedIndex ==  ribbon.Items.Count -1)
    {
      ribbon.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      ribbon.SelectedIndex++;
    }
  }
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: No, there is another problem. If user selects tab by clicking on "Tab" button and then selects tab using mouse, and then clicks few times on "Tab" button, current selected tab switches to tab which was selected by "Tab" button. I don't want switch tab. You can add more RibbonTabs to see the problem.

Comment: Sry what do you exactly mean with "Tab" button?
Is it the TabKey or do you have some kind of navigation button which switches the tabs?

Comment: I mean tab button on keyboard